# Start Yakuake with split

Tags: command-line, kde, yakuake

I love Yakuake functionality but every time I start I have to split the screens for my use. Is there any way to start split?

Answer (score 0):

Auto answer:

I can find a solution in Arch Wiki, it's creating a script at yakuake's start.

[yakuake start](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yakuake#Installation)